# How to get Form data as a Map in Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a complicated html form that dynamically created with java script.

I want to get the map of key-value pairs as a Map in java and store them.

here is my controller to get the submitted data.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String createRole(Hashmap<String, Object) keyVals) {
    ....
}
```

but my map is empty.

How can i get form data as a map of name-value pairs in Spring mvc controller?

Comment: Add `@RequestParam` to your method argument.

Comment: I donno what the param name is! i found a solution to my problem posted below.

Comment: You don't need a param name just the annotation. `@RequestParam` on the type map will give you all request parameters.

Comment: yeah it did a job;I've just tested your solution everything is ok and definitely better solution tan mine. But there is a problem multiselect values just returns first selected item! not all of the selected values!! when i get the params from HttpServletRequest multiselects works fine! any idea??

Comment: Instead of `Map` use `MultiValueMap`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can also use **`@RequestBody`** with **`MultiValueMap`**
e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create",
                method=RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String createRole(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData){
 // your code goes here
}
```

Now you can get parameter names and their values.

**MultiValueMap** is in Spring utils package

Comment: I am getting "Content Type is not supported" issue

Comment: Make sure the Content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, that got rid of the content type not supported.

Comment: On my side, I get stuck since I've migrated to Spring Boot 2.6. There is no data in received @RequestBody variable.

Answer (score 9):

I,ve just found a solution

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST, 
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String createRole(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
    ...
}
```

this way i have a map of submitted parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String createRole(@RequestParam HashMap<String, String> formData) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above already correctly point out that @RequestParam annotation is missing. Just to add why thta is required,

A simple GET request would be soemthing like :

```
http://localhost:8080/api/foos?id=abc
```

In controller, we need to map the function paramter to the parameter in the GET request. So we write the controller as

```
@GetMapping("/api/foos")
@ResponseBody
public String getFoos(@RequestParam String id) {
    return "ID: " + id;
}
```

and add @RequestParam for the mapping of the paramter "id".

Comment: I like having the "why", thanks for that.  your explanation would be improved if it were in the context of the OP's question, specifically, a POST request.